# How to remove duplicates when distinct doesnt work in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a very small question

I have a table co_fields which has a varchar column templateid which is all numbers in it,

if I try

```
select templateid, templateid + 500 
from co_fields
```

it works fine but I got lot of duplicate records , how can I remove the duplicate records :

current result after running the query is:

```
tempateid   | templateid+500
1000             1500
1000             1500
1000             1500
1000             1500
2000             2500
2000             2500
```

expected result:

```
templateid  | templateid+500
1000              1500
2000              2500
```

thanks

Comment: templateid  | templateid+500          1000              1500
2000              2500

Comment: what you mean `distinct` doesnt work?

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a `varchar2` column? Use the correct data type. If distinct really isn't working (whatever that means), maybe you have trailing spaces on some values?

Answer (score 2):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fbe77/4)**

```
select DISTINCT templateid, templateid + 500 
from co_fields
```

OR

```
select "tempateid", "tempateid" + 500 
from co_fields
GROUP BY "tempateid";
```

After Alex Poole comment you should try `length` to detect trailing spaces or special chars

```
select DISTINCT templateid, templateid + 500, length(templateid)
from co_fields
```

Comment: A trailing space [would 'break' distinct](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2d40f/1); no idea if that is what is actually happening, it's just a guess, but trim would ['fix' it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2d40f/3) obviously. But even then there's an underlying data problem (and a data type problem!).

Comment: @AlexPoole In that case the `group by` version will also show the same `doesnt work` result.

Comment: Yes, the Fiddle shows that. The OP hasn't said they've tried `group by` or that it works when distinct doesn't. The behaviour will be the same for both whatever is really wrong - at least I can't think how it would be different.

Comment: @AlexPoole I update my answer to provide one altern solution to detect that.

Comment: It would help if the OP responded to your comment on the question too, of course, as it's still a guess *8-)

Answer (score 0):

maybe using a group by can work for your case, check next link :)
[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY column ;
```